# is this a javac bug or some error in my code

Tags: java, javac

When I run my Ant script, I get the following error

```
  compile-src:
     [echo] Source include pattern                = **/*.java
     [echo] Source exclude pattern                = 
     [echo] Compiling From Source:                = /u1/cibuild/.hudson/jobs/LDICommon/workspace/src
    [javac] Compiling 99 source files to /u1/cibuild/.hudson/jobs/LDICommon/workspace/dbg1.5/classes/src
    [javac] An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.5.0_09). Please file a bug at the Java Developer Connection (http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport)  after checking the Bug Parade for duplicates. Include your program and the following diagnostic in your report.  Thank you.
    [javac] java.lang.AssertionError: {rawtypes}
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeMaker$AnnotationBuilder.visitArray(TreeMaker.java:634)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Attribute$Array.accept(Attribute.java:124)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeMaker$AnnotationBuilder.translate(TreeMaker.java:637)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeMaker$AnnotationBuilder.visitCompoundInternal(TreeMaker.java:628)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeMaker$AnnotationBuilder.translate(TreeMaker.java:641)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeMaker.Annotation(TreeMaker.java:649)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeMaker.Annotations(TreeMaker.java:570)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeMaker.VarDef(TreeMaker.java:554)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.visitIterableForeachLoop(Lower.java:2892)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.visitForeachLoop(Lower.java:2755)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.Tree$ForeachLoop.accept(Tree.java:597)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.translate(Lower.java:1881)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:54)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.visitBlock(TreeTranslator.java:145)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.visitBlock(Lower.java:2927)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.Tree$Block.accept(Tree.java:535)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.translate(Lower.java:1881)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:54)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.visitBlock(TreeTranslator.java:145)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.visitBlock(Lower.java:2927)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.Tree$Block.accept(Tree.java:535)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.translate(Lower.java:1881)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.visitForLoop(Lower.java:2948)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.Tree$ForLoop.accept(Tree.java:581)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.translate(Lower.java:1881)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.visitIterableForeachLoop(Lower.java:2894)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.visitForeachLoop(Lower.java:2755)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.Tree$ForeachLoop.accept(Tree.java:597)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.translate(Lower.java:1881)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:54)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.visitBlock(TreeTranslator.java:145)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.visitBlock(Lower.java:2927)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.Tree$Block.accept(Tree.java:535)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.translate(Lower.java:1881)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.visitIf(Lower.java:2382)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.Tree$If.accept(Tree.java:715)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.translate(Lower.java:1881)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:54)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.visitBlock(TreeTranslator.java:145)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.visitBlock(Lower.java:2927)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.Tree$Block.accept(Tree.java:535)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.translate(Lower.java:1881)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.visitIf(Lower.java:2383)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.Tree$If.accept(Tree.java:715)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.translate(Lower.java:1881)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:54)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.visitBlock(TreeTranslator.java:145)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.visitBlock(Lower.java:2927)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.Tree$Block.accept(Tree.java:535)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.translate(Lower.java:1881)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.visitMethodDef(TreeTranslator.java:129)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.visitMethodDefInternal(Lower.java:2267)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.visitMethodDef(Lower.java:2186)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.Tree$MethodDef.accept(Tree.java:478)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.translate(Lower.java:1881)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.visitClassDef(Lower.java:1989)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.Tree$ClassDef.accept(Tree.java:434)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.translate(Lower.java:1881)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.translate(Lower.java:1901)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.translateTopLevelClass(Lower.java:3064)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:487)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:592)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:544)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.Main.compile(Main.java:67)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.Main.main(Main.java:52)

BUILD FAILED
```

I'm not sure what is going on, I can compile this project outside ant (in eclipse) without an issue.

I'm almost sure that the message about a bug in the compiler is a red herring, I suspect the real problem has to do with the message:

```
[javac] java.lang.AssertionError: {rawtypes}
```

but there isn't much information to help tracking down the root cause of the error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is eclipse and ant using the same javac version?

Comment: Try to use a different version of JVM. In this case you are using 1.5, Are you sure that you don't have to use newer or older?

Comment: @Peter Lawrey, I'm not sure what you mean? would be helpful if you can point me to where I got a valid answer and I didn't accept it...

Comment: @Amir Raminfar no, it's a bit awkward, the build system is using an older version (which I can't change), and I can't find this version for my eclipse.

Comment: @Charbel Given that the version of jvm has to be 1.5_9 you should reproduce the same behavior of the ant file on eclipse, check for the dependencies.

Comment: If you can't change the build system, you could at least try to replicate it with a newer JDK (the latest 1.5 version, for example), and see if the problem still occurs.

Comment: @Shilaghae - you are visible of course ;) thanks all, I'll try to build and see.

Answer (score 2):

Given your compiler is really old and not publicly supported, I would assume that upgrading your JDK would be a good starting place.

The last free version of Java 5.0 is update 22 (you have update 9).
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index-jdk5-jsp-142662.html

The latest version of Java is Java 6 update 26.
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index-jsp-138363.html

Answer (score 2):

It clearly says that it is a compiler bug:

> An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.5.0_09). Please file a bug at the
>   Java Developer Connection (http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport)  after
>   checking the Bug Parade for duplicates. Include your program and the following
>   diagnostic in your report.  Thank you.

As Peter said, first check if the same problem occurs in a newer javac version, and then file a bug report. (You might try to minimize down your code to an SSCEE first.)

Eclipse does not use javac, but has its own compiler included, thus this does not tell us anything here.